# Android low connectivity cancel async http task

Tags: android, networking, android-asynctask

I have a foreground service that runs all of my upload/download media files(audio, video, pictures) from the server. For plain text messages, I use an AsyncTask to send the message to the server.
While the messages are uploading or downloading, I display a progress bar next to the message.

I was told that while using the app, sometimes the text messages does not go through for a long time and the progress bar remains spinning.
This is how I get the default httpclient for all of my http requests.

```
private static DefaultHttpClient httpclient;  // my static httpclient

 public synchronized static DefaultHttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
    if(httpclient!=null){
        Log.d(TAG, "returning existing httpclient");
        return httpclient;      
    }

    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "creating new httpclient");

        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore
                .getDefaultType());
        trustStore.load(null, null);

        SSLSocketFactory sf = new SixDegreeSSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
        sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);


        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory
                .getSocketFactory(), 80));
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 6 * 1000);
        ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(
                params, registry);
        ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, 6000);
        httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient(ccm,params);
        return httpclient;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Exception creating defaultClient");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new DefaultHttpClient();
    } 
}
```

I have used the connection timeout. I execute the http post in the doInBackground method of the AsyncTask

```
@Override      
protected Boolean doInBackground(Object... argList) {       
try {           
HttpResponse response;   

if (this.requestMethod.equals(GET)) {

            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            response = client.execute(httpGet);

        } else {

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            Log.d(TAG, "http post ");
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            if (values != null) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : values.entrySet()) {
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(entry
                            .getKey(), entry.getValue()));
                }
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
            }

            response = client.execute(httpPost);
            Log.d(TAG, "client execute");
        }

        /* setting a response code. */
        this.responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

        returnflag = (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK);

        // Get the response
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        try{
            if (returnflag) {
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()));
                String line = "";               
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                str.append(line);
                }
                rd.close();
            }
        } finally{
            try{
                if(response.getEntity()!=null)
                    response.getEntity().consumeContent();  // consume the entity content
            } catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        this.responseString = str.toString();

    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        System.out.println(TAG + " UnknownHostException ");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(TAG + " responseCode " + responseCode);
        e.printStackTrace();
        returnflag = false;
    }
    catch (NullPointerException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        returnflag = false;
    }
    catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex)
    {   ex.printStackTrace();
        returnflag = false;
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {

    }

    return returnflag;
    }
```

Based on the boolean returnflag I process the result in postExecute, where extendedHandler is an an instance of the interface that I implement in the activities

```
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
if(result) {
        iRequester.onRequestSuccess(responseString, requestCode);
        if(extendedHandler != null) extendedHandler.onRequestSuccessExtended(responseString,    requestCode, this.tagData);
    }
    else {
        iRequester.onRequestFailure(responseCode, requestCode);
        if(extendedHandler != null) extendedHandler.onRequestFailureExtended(responseCode, requestCode, this.tagData);
    }

}
```

Under this implementation, if the connectivity is poor, how should I handle it or cancel the tast after certain time. I am not sure if just using the HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout would work. Before cancelling the task, is there any way to know if the message is delivered to the server and it's just waiting for the response.
Please let me know if any of this needs more clarification.

Thank you

Comment: `setConnectionTimeout` had worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Why not sending an ACK back from the server to confirm that the text has been successfully received?

A confirmation result in JSON format:

```
{status: "ok")
```

Comment: I do get a response from the server in JSON if it successfull. And based on that i remove the progress bar of the message.

Comment: `final int TIMEOUT=5000;` and use it in `HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout` and a timer as well, the timer would stop the task and show a message that the connection is not stable/slow...etc

Comment: I do get a response from the server in JSON if it successfull. based on that i remove the progress bar of the message. The problem is thatduring low connectivity, the progress bar is spinning for a long time, which I'm thinking is because it never received a response from the server. I am trying to find how I can handle requests during those particular instances where connectivity is poor. And lets say they send a text message, progress bar is displayed and its taking time and they close the app then the asynctask is gone, and it can never process the response from the server.

Comment: Or you can even define a broadcast receiver for internet connectivity and have a connectivity flag and stop the task when the connection time is out and the flag is set to false.

Comment: I could definitely implement that but my concern is if the time out occurs after the message is inserted in our server database but has yet to send back JSON response, then it would be displaying message failure on the device and on re-sending the message could result in duplication. I am not sure if that made sense